# Getting pointer issue in C program

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, subscript-operator

As we know that arrays are passed by pointers only in C then `swap1(arr[i],arr[j])` below means that two
pointers will be passed to the function `swap1()` then why `swap1(arr[i],arr[j])` is giving me error? According to function prototype of `swap1()` two pointer should be passed and I am passing that.

On the other hand, when I am passing actually the address `swap1(&arr[i],&arr[j])` it is working fine, which is obvious.

```
void swap1(int *a,int *b){
   int temp = *a;
   *a = *b;
   *b = temp;
}
void bubble(int arr[], int i, int n)
{
    for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
        if(arr[i]>arr[j])
        swap1(arr[i],arr[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Turn on all warnings and errors (`-Wall -Wextra -Werror`), this [should not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/uFA6q2).

Answer (score 2):

In the `bubble` function the variable `arr` is a pointer (type `int *`). That means `arr[i]` (for any `i`) is *not* a pointer, it's an `int` *value*.

When you pass those `int` values to `swap` the compiler should complain about it, and it's correct because the `swap` function expects pointers (again of type `int *`).

To get a pointer to `arr[i]` you need to use the address-of operator `&`, as in `&arr[i]`:

```
swap1(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

when `arr` is an array, indeed passing arr is actually passing a pointer to the first element. however when you use the deference operator `[i]`, you pass the value of the `i-th` element and not its address.

Answer (score 0):

From the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
>   is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
>   definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
>   (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
>   binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
>   to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
>   **E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1** (counting from zero).

So when you call the function like

```
swap1(arr[i],arr[j]);
```

you are passing the values of the two elements of the array. To pass pointers to these elements you could write

```
swap1( arr + i, arr + j );
```

The difference will be obvious if the first call to rewrite as it is written in the quote from the C Standard

```
swap1(arr[i],arr[j]);
```

is equivalent to

```
swap1( *( arr + i ), *( arr +j ) );
```

that is the pointers are dereferenced before passing the control to the function.